# Некорректная ссылка в выводе товара

Tags: modx, minishop2

Собственно, столкнулась с такой проблемой: в превью товара название ссылается на другую страницу. Картинка - имеет верную ссылку товара.

[image: Пример на сайте]

Коррекция:
Найдена возможная ошибка в tpl.output
[image: output]

Учитывая, то, что я даже отдаленно не программист - прошу не бить) Подскажите, как исправить ситуацию и что должно быть прописано для корректного вывода ссылок?

Comment: ну в шаблоне у Вас действительно ссылка указана одна единственная. От этого она и на сайте такая. Судя по всему Вас требуется заменить ссылку, которая выделена на картинке на `<a href="[[+uri]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, я это сама обнаружила и сделала скриншот) Я не программист, даже отдаленно, и хотела помощи - в каком Чанке, хоть рядом, этот баг) Этот момент найден и устранен, проблема оказалась еще глобальнее - кривые ручки и обновление minishop2